# Spring project - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am asking this question because I've already found questions which are about this issue - but in my case I cannot find any alias or column name being too long.

This is the line where the Entity gets saved (CSVService line 262 - you will see that the Exception points to this line):

```
    lagerverantwortlicherList.forEach(data -> lagerverRepository.save(data));
```

This is the entity I am trying to save:

```
@Entity
public class Lagerverantwortlicher {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LagerverantwortlicherPK Id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="residentId", nullable = false)
    private Resident resident;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lagerId", referencedColumnName = "lagerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Lager lager;

    public Lagerverantwortlicher() {
    }

    public Lagerverantwortlicher(LagerverantwortlicherPK lagerverantwortlicherId, Resident resident) {
        this.Id = lagerverantwortlicherId;
        this.resident = resident;
    }

    //getter und setter



    public Lager getLager() {
        return lager;
    }

    public void setLager(Lager lager) {
        this.lager = lager;
    }

    public LagerverantwortlicherPK getLagerverantwortlicherId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setLagerverantwortlicherId(LagerverantwortlicherPK lagerverantwortlicherId) {
        this.Id = lagerverantwortlicherId;
    }

    public Resident getResident() {
        return resident;
    }

    public void setResident(Resident resident) {
        this.resident = resident;
    }

    //toString

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lagerverantwortlicher{" +
                "lagerverantwortlicherId=" + Id +
                ", resident=" + resident +
                ", lager=" + lager +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the PK-class:

```
@Embeddable
public class LagerverantwortlicherPK implements Serializable {

    private Long lagerId;

    private LocalDate gueltigAb;

    public LagerverantwortlicherPK() {

    }

    public LagerverantwortlicherPK(Long lager, LocalDate gueltigAb) {
        this.lagerId = lager;
        this.gueltigAb = gueltigAb;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        LagerverantwortlicherPK that = (LagerverantwortlicherPK) o;
        return Objects.equals(lagerId, that.lagerId) &&
                Objects.equals(gueltigAb, that.gueltigAb);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(lagerId, gueltigAb);
    }

    //toString

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LagerverantwortlicherPK{" +
                "lagerId=" + lagerId +
                ", gueltigAb=" + gueltigAb +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.save(Unknown Source)
 -----> at com.chantal.service.CSVService.lambda$saveData$7(CSVService.java:262)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at com.chantal.service.CSVService.saveData(CSVService.java:262)
        at com.chantal.bl.MainGUI$1.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:119)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:438)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:233)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.merge(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:520)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:505)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        ... 97 more
```

Comment: enable SQL logging, and you'll know which SQL query is being executed. And thus know which identifier is too long.

Comment: Did you check DB permisson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I had already enabled SQL logging but couldn't find anything, than I wrote a program to find all strings which are longer than 30 characters and I got it!

The problem was that in order to execute the insert of this entity, some data had to be fetched - and in this data the column name was too long.

But for those who want to enable sql logging in spring:

insert this into your application.properties-file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-00972 says identifier is greater than 30 characters long. It can be a column name, table name or alias. You must be creating something which is breaking the rule. Enable finer logging on the SQL, you will get to know which statement is going wrong.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#sthref727

Answer (score 0):

I also faced to this problem. This problem's answer is simply. If your query inclued '*AS*' keyword than you should take short idendifier.

For example:

**Wrong Usage:**

```
SELECT p.prodId AS MySpecialTooLongProdId FROM Product p
```

**Correct Usage:**

```
SELECT p.prodId AS ProductId FROM Product p
```